# DateTime Setting dates for next day

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, google-api, calendar

I have a Google API that takes date and time and sets up a event in customers calendar and the problem is I am using date time to add hours to the event when I boot time for  12pm noon  For whatever reason, it will be listed in my Google Calendar for the day after at 12am.

Here is the code that sets up the date and the time:

```
// dd is a drop down for hours 1 to 12 Central Time Zone
int iHour = Convert.ToInt32(dd.SelectedItem.Text);
// and this is the minutes  values of 30 or 45
int iMinute = Convert.ToInt32(ddMinute.SelectedItem.Text);
var date = "Nov 19, 2017";
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

// If its PM set 12 hours more to it because its a 24 hours clock 
if (ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue == "PM")
    iHour += 12;

dt = dt.AddHours(iHour);
dt = dt.AddMinutes(iMinute);

var startDate = dt;
var endDate = dt;

string sNotes = "TestingA PI";
string sTitle = "Testas" + " with: " + "ASP.NEt" + " " + "Last Name here";


int length = Convert.ToInt32("30");
endDate = endDate.AddMinutes(length);

var google = new GoogleCalendar();
int value = google.CreateCalendarEvent("email", startDate, endDate, sNotes, sTitle);
```

Can any one see where did I do this wrong

Comment: Hours from 1 to 12 let me add that to the question

Comment: Check the 24hours time format. There is a possibility that adding 12 add iHour causes this to happen

Comment: Why do you convert a hardcoded string to an int here: `int length = Convert.ToInt32("30");` instead of just using a hard coded int: `int length = 30;`?

Comment: Its not hardcoded its a drop down for users to select from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue == "PM") // If its PM set 12 hours more to it because its a 24 hours clock 
       iHour += 12;
```

should be:

```
if (ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue == "PM" && iHour < 12) // If its 1-11 PM set 12 hours more to it because its a 24 hours clock 
    iHour += 12;
else if (ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue == "AM" && iHour == 12) 
    iHour = 0;
```

*Since 12 + 12 is 24, and today plus 24 hours is the next day.*

Another way to write it:

```
if (iHour == 12) // 12 is **before** 1
    iHour = 0;

if (ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue == "PM") // If its PM set 12 hours more to it because its a 24 hours clock 
    iHour += 12;
```

Comment: I like the second way you wrote it - convert the 12 to 0 (to military time) right off the bat. Then there's no additional comparisons needed on `iHour`.

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: Got it that was the reason it was confused thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do it is to construct a date string in a specific format (including the AM or PM designation), and then use `DateTime.ParseExact` to create your `startDate`. This way you don't have to do all the conversion from string to int, then add 12 hours if PM was specified, etc.

For example, this code would replace everything you currently have up to and including the `startDate` assignment:

```
// This assumes that ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue will be "AM" or "PM"
var dateString = string.Format("Nov 19, 2017 {0}:{1} {2}", dd.SelectedItem.Text, 
    ddMinute.SelectedItem.Text, ddAptAmPm.SelectedValue);

// In a format string, tt is a placeholder for AM/PM
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MMM dd, yyyy h:m tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can read more about Date and Time Format Strings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Tried that its a way of doing so thanks I will keep this in mind